# What kind of English that the narration of the starting part of A.I. movie?

Tags: pronunciation, intonation

I'm watching the [A.I. Artificial Intelligence](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/?ref_=nv_sr_1).
And I just realized that the pronunciation and intonation is special.

The pronunciation is very strict. Hear the part `.. economic link` the `c` ends with `k` before the `l` is said.

I thought that's some England's style but the intonation is not what I've known.

Is it just an elegant way to speak?

Comment: Most people won't have seen this movie, and those that have (like myself) will not remember the specific accents used. Can you find a YouTube link where the characters are speaking the way you describe? Please [edit] that link into your question as, very importantly, a *timestamp of when the interesting speech begins* as well as a transcription of what's said (no one wants to watch a 20 minute video hoping to find the 6 seconds interesting accents).

Comment: Perhaps _precise, clipped_ intonation.

Comment: I found it. It was [Ben Kingsley](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001426/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t54)'s voice. What an English it was.

Comment: You could do worse than to imitate a Shakespearean actor. Actually, you can. Repeat that sound when you are in the movies and soften it when you speak to people. Nothing marks the appreciative tourist more than the overly distinct GRAH-see-AAHS instead of GRA-ci-ah.